# How to collect Laravel mails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I'd like to store all outgoing emails sent by laravel in my database.

I know that I can have additional code before sending each email, but I prefer it to be event-like and cover all emails because my app has so many classes that sends out emails and I don't like duplicated code.

Can you give me some hint how can I collect emails?

Thank you.

Comment: create one class which will have send and save mail code and pass your send mail information to it, from other classes of your project

Comment: there is a great tutorial of how you can implement this - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events

Comment: I found that laravel triggers an event named mail.sending. I will try tomorrow and let you guys now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a while I found that Swift triggers an event named "mailer.send" so I create an Event Listener for "mailer.send" and it worked.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L391